# How can I save the qutoe to a specific weekday?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to start to say thank you for all your help I already got from the community(beginner).

My problem
Now it's just stores in the local storage, what I want to do is save it to a specific weekday, so they can have a different quote for every weekday.

```
function saveEdits() {

var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");
     
var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
    
console.log(userVersion)
        
localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;
        
document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Saved";

}
    
function checkEdits() {     

if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)

document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
}
```

html

> Where attention goes energy flows
>
> Tony Robbins

Comment: You could approach the problem a couple of different ways. One way would be to keep track of the quotes in a key/value pair object. The other would be to have a separate local storage for each day of the week.

Comment: Hi André, I would love to have a seperate local storage for each day, but I can not find where I can learn how to do it :(, I also don't know how to receive the users data on a specific day.. maybe I took too much water over my head..